# Sticky navbar flickering on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I have a sticky navbar with a text that should disappear on scroll. If the content of that text is more than a couple of lines, the navbar will flicker. I think this is related to the element having a significant change in the document height, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I've switched it from display: none to visibility: hidden as suggested in a previous thread. It went from flickering on all content to only longer paragraphs. I've also attempted to add a delay to the effect but I can't seem to respond to the actual issue of having the document height change, and thus the scrolling position changed which is probably causing the flickering effect.

```js
var $win = $(window)
var $doc = $(document)

$win.scroll(function(e) {
  scrollEffects();
});

function scrollEffects() {
  var limit = 85;
  var scrolled = $win.scrollTop();
  if ($doc.scrollTop() >= limit) {
    $(".intro").addClass('inactive');
    //$('#banner-contents').css('opacity', 1 - (scrolled * .00280));
    // console.log('scrolled');
  } else {
    $(".intro").removeClass('inactive');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
  background: tomato;
}

.nav {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

.intro {
  color: $black;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 7rem;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease;
}

.inactive {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <p class="intro">
    This is some text that should disappear without flickering <br> This is some text that should disappear without flickering <br> This is some text that should <strong>disappear</strong> without flickering <br> This is some text that should disappear
    without flickering <br> This is some text that should disappear without flickering <br>
  </p>
  Other text Other text Other text Other text
</div>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent dapibus finibus lorem, sed pulvinar est vestibulum et. Nunc semper ligula eget urna imperdiet ullamcorper. Etiam tristique consectetur ornare. Vestibulum ipsum mi, ultrices vitae tincidunt
  non, ornare sit amet dolor. Maecenas convallis sollicitudin nibh, in laoreet leo tristique eget. Donec vitae auctor risus. Integer mattis nibh ipsum, nec porttitor ligula commodo ac. Etiam pharetra elit sit amet magna hendrerit scelerisque. Nam vel
  imperdiet metus. Vestibulum lectus enim, tempus sed orci ut, fermentum consectetur nisl. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec ut eros ex. Quisque lacinia viverra mauris sit amet convallis.
  Phasellus in neque risus. Quisque rutrum lacinia erat in cursus. Praesent imperdiet et est vitae tincidunt. Nulla leo massa, tempor consequat tincidunt aliquet, blandit id libero. Nullam condimentum dapibus dictum. Sed vel magna dignissim, maximus augue
  non, laoreet ante. Ut urna velit, porta vel mauris sit amet, suscipit efficitur nisi. Integer cursus bibendum tortor sit amet tempor. Proin eget turpis ipsum. Maecenas et quam ornare, imperdiet turpis mattis, fermentum diam. Mauris blandit fringilla
  euismod. Fusce in nunc est. Morbi fringilla pulvinar massa, pulvinar auctor ex eleifend ut. Integer eros lorem, viverra et tincidunt nec, aliquet at erat. Morbi sed dapibus eros. Nunc tristique ullamcorper porttitor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad
  litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed malesuada nunc tincidunt, faucibus purus eu, ultrices velit. Fusce non velit diam. Praesent ac vulputate libero, et dignissim justo. Mauris at felis efficitur dolor tincidunt hendrerit
  id at lacus. Curabitur sit amet elit arcu. Donec a elit felis. Aliquam laoreet placerat velit, sed molestie nisl congue vitae. Ut aliquet aliquam tincidunt. In ultricies suscipit efficitur. Sed ultrices ligula dui, non sodales massa pulvinar in. Nulla
  accumsan risus quam, sit amet mattis orci facilisis eget. Curabitur tempor porttitor nibh ac ultrices. Integer scelerisque, elit at auctor consectetur, leo enim pellentesque sem, et tristique nisl sem in magna. Aliquam vel egestas sapien. Fusce blandit
  lectus vitae molestie egestas. Aliquam varius, risus et viverra dapibus, urna tellus condimentum nisi, eget vehicula sapien risus eu neque. Praesent at tristique massa, at cursus nibh. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam cursus consequat bibendum. Sed suscipit
  ac dui vitae fermentum.
</p>
```

Comment: I clicked on 'Inspect Element' on the paragraph and I figured out that it's flickering because it removes class .inactive and adds it back again constantly. Somehow it constantly goes in both the if and the else statement when you scroll down slowly. I am suspecting it's the max-height:0 in .inactive, which is changing the doc.scrollTop's value and interfering with your code

Comment: The class inactive also has visibility:hidden which is making the element disappear, which is the purpose of this effect. Or perhaps you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

You just replce your's css with this css on .class(.nav) i will be fixed

```
.nav {
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```